# Java Events: Printing an ArrayList that Stores Names on Button Press

Tags: java, events, arraylist, javafx

I have a scene set up that allows a user to enter names in a text field and stores the name in an ArrayList once the button "Add Employee" is pressed. I want to print all of the contents in the ArrayList in the console once the user clicks on the "Print Names" button. I have methods to handle both of these events but for some reason only the last name stored is being printed. I am positive that each name is not being stored and to ensure that they are, a loop needs to be implemented somewhere.

Here is the code. All of the appropriate libraries have been imported. I have excluded those for brevity.

```
public class ComboBoxTest extends Application
{
    ArrayList<String> empNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        //hbox for label, textfield, and add button
        HBox panes = new HBox();
        panes.setSpacing(10);
        panes.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //create label and textfield for employee name
        Label empName = new Label("Employee name");
        TextField empTField = new TextField();
        Tooltip empTooltip = new Tooltip("Employee name");
        empTField.setTooltip(empTooltip);

        //add employee button and properties
        Button addEmpBtn = new Button("Add Employee");
        addEmpBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Tooltip addEmpToolTip = new Tooltip("Add employee");
        //addEmpBtn.setTooltip(addEmpToolTip);

        //print employee names button
        Button printEmpNamesBtn = new Button("Print Names");
        Tooltip printToolTip = new Tooltip("Print");
        //printEmpNamesBtn.setTooltip(printToolTip);

        //hbox to line up the "print names" button
        HBox printEmpOperation = new HBox();
        printEmpOperation.setSpacing(10);
        printEmpOperation.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        //add button to the hbox
        printEmpOperation.getChildren().addAll(printEmpNamesBtn);

        //actions for the buttons that are clicked
        addEmpBtn.setOnAction(e -> empNames = addEmployeeNames(panes, empTField));

        printEmpNamesBtn.setOnAction(e -> printEmployeeNames(empNames));

        //add label, text field, and add button to the pane
        panes.getChildren().addAll(empName, empTField, addEmpBtn);

        BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane(panes);
        BorderPane.setMargin(panes, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        bPane.setBottom(printEmpOperation);
        //bPane.setMargin(panes, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(bPane, bPane.getPrefWidth(), bPane.getPrefHeight());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Add Employees");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //method should add each name entered in the textfield to an array
    public static ArrayList<String> addEmployeeNames(HBox pane, TextField tf)
    {

        ArrayList<String> empNames = new ArrayList<>();
        empNames.add(tf.getText());

        tf.clear();

        return empNames;
    }

    //method should print every name stored in the array
    public static void printEmployeeNames(ArrayList<String> e)
    {
        System.out.println("Employee Names:");
        System.out.println("---------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(e.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're instantiating a new ArrayList object everytime you call addEmployeeNames, so naturally after the last call to that function you will have an ArrayList with only one entry, the last you added.
You should define that function so it accepts the ArrayList collection of employees as a parameter and add your data to it so you can call it like

```
empNames = addEmployeeNames(panes, empTField, empNames)
```

Then, it should be

```
    public static ArrayList<String> addEmployeeNames(HBox pane, TextField tf, ArrayList<String> employees)
{
    employees.add(tf.getText());

    tf.clear();

    return employees;
}
```